# Custom Post Type rewrite redirects to homepage

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type registered called `employees`. When registering this custom post type I used:

```
...
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'people'),
...
```

Now, when I hover over a link to one of my employees I see the url as this:

```
www.example.com/people/john
```

So that seems correct. But I click the link, I see Chrome navigate to just `www.example.com/john` and then that doesn't exist so it redirects to `www.example.com` (the homepage).

How do I make it navigate to `/people/john` and stop it from redirecting to the homepage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most important args for rewrite redirects when registering new post type are:

- 'public' => true,
- 'publicly_queryable' => true,
- 'query_var' => true,

**I have pasted some code below which I have tested and it working fine for the url : www.example.com/people/john**

```
$labels_employee = 
array('name'       => _x( 'Employees', 'Post typegeneral name', 'textdomain' ),
'singular_name'    => _x( 'Employee', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
'menu_name'        => _x( 'Employees', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
'name_admin_bar'   => _x( 'Employee', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
'add_new'          => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
'add_new_item'     => __( 'Add New Employee', 'textdomain' ),
'new_item'         => __( 'New Employee', 'textdomain' ),

$args_employee= array(
            'labels'             => $labels_employee,
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'people' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    );

register_post_type( 'employee', $args_employee );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem was definitely `public_queryable`. I had it to false and that ended up redirecting traffic. Thank you,

Comment: Problem for me was `public_queryable` as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you have register your taxo with
register_post_type('employees',$args);

have you create single-employees.php ?

and after in administration / Setting / Permalinks -> Save Changes

Comment: Re-saving permalinks solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, custom taxonomy link was redirecting to index.

Ok, when register a custom taxonomy, make sure that the register_taxonomy code runs always (init hook) and not only on admin (admin_init)

```
add_action('init', 'woobr_register_settings');
function woobr_register_settings()
{
    $args = array(
        //'labels' => $labels,
        //'labels' => 'Brand',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'product',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'),

    );

    register_taxonomy('woobrand', 'product', $args); 
}
```

Comment: This is a good point. Can you give a code example of how to achieve that?

Comment: Added just now.